# SSH permission denied error

Tags: unix, hadoop

I am trying to follow [this](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/spinning-up-a-free-hadoop-cluster-step-by-step-c406d56bae42#.n5324aps6) article but But I am getting error while trying to ssh into the datanode server is there anything wrong?(this command is just above hadoop)
Please help me figure out the issue

```
$ ssh -v ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-xxxxxx-2.compute.amazonaws.com

debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxx-2.compute.amazonaws.com [xx-xx-xx-xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 8c:b6:90:4a:5d:97:8c:47:e1:96:dd:42:82:4a:56:a5
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

.ssh file content:

```
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  400 Aug 24 04:35 authorized_keys_bkp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Aug 25 02:37 authorized_keys’
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1692 Aug 25 02:39 AmitKeyPari_Oregon.pem
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Aug 25 02:39 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  405 Aug 25 02:40 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1766 Aug 25 02:40 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  805 Aug 25 02:40 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  444 Aug 25 02:41 known_hosts
```

Comment: post the directory and file permission `.ssh` directory and its contents.

Comment: Hi edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your public key is in the list of authorized keys on the server side.  (copy it into the server-side .ssh/authorized_keys file)

Comment: It seems it is as mentioed in the error message above.                      
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:3

Comment: No, that is the key for the machine.  It tells you that encyption to the machine is not being hit with a man-in-the-middle attack (or at least that it's not a NEW MITM attack since the keys were exchanged).  Your public key is different; it is a personal key, not a host key, that tells the other machine to trust your private key when you try to log into a particular account on the server.

Comment: @Amit I believe that just means that it recognizes the host, as you have tried to connect to it before, but that doesn't necessarily mean you have a valid authentication key

Comment: I followed the same command as mentioned in the article I am following...

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh datanode1 ‘cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys’

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with the directory structure.

Can someone help me with the issue.

Comment: .ssh is a directory.  Assuming that is your server-side .ssh directory, look at the keys that are in authorized_keys and compare them against your client-side id_rsa.pub